# Getting 500 error while requesting to webservice using Ajax AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

**Scenario:**

I'm working on a webform(MVC) project in which I had to use Web Service in Ajax AutoCompleteExtender control for searching purpose. First of all I checked `HelloWorld()` service which is working fine but when I create my custom web service named as `GetParentID` and make a request on it. It shows me 500 error message which is defined in below snap:

[image]

**Below is my Default.aspx.cs code:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
    runat="server"
    ServiceMethod="GetParentID"
    ServicePath="~/Services.asmx"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    UseContextKey="false"
    CompletionInterval="0" 
    EnableCaching="true" 
    CompletionSetCount="30" 
    FirstRowSelected="true">


</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**Below is my Service.asmx.cs code:**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public string[] GetParentID(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr[0] = "Adil";
        dr[0] = "Ahmer";
        dr[0] = "Kamran";
        dr[0] = "Fasih";
        dr[0] = "Azeem";
        dr[0] = "Rana";
        dr[0] = "Humza";
        dr[0] = "Waleed";
        dr[0] = "Faizan Rafiq";
        dr[0] = "Mohsin";
        dr[0] = "Ahsan";
        dr[0] = "Arshad Ahmed";
        dr[0] = "Uncle Majboor";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //DataTable dt = null;
        DataView dv = null;
        List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
        //dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["ParentID"];

        if ((dt != null))
        {
            dv = dt.Copy().DefaultView;
            dv.RowFilter = "Name like  '%" + prefixText + "%' ";
            dv.Sort = "ID Asc";

            string c = prefixText;
            double Num = 0;
            bool isNum = double.TryParse(c, out Num);
            int indx = 0;

            foreach (DataRowView dvr in dv)
            {
                if (indx <= count)
                {
                    suggestions.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(dvr["Name"].ToString(), dvr["Name"].ToString()));
                    indx += 1;
                }

            }
        }
        return suggestions.ToArray();
    }
```

I don't know how to deal with asmx web services. This is my first try. Mostly I make a request using javascript / jquery ajax calls. Below is my prerequisites which I'm using in my this application. Also I attached complete github repository link so you guys easily help me on this matter.

[github](https://github.com/AhmerAli/rsms)

Solution created on VS 2013

Dot net framework 4.5

AjaxControlToolKit

AjaxControlToolkit.Installer.17.1.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are calling that web method using AJAX. Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
//    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

So just uncomment the line and it will start working.

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Comment: IDK how I miss this little comment code but you deserve thanks and upvoted.